# Google Login/Signin on Yandex Android extension

Tags: android, google-chrome-extension, google-signin, yandex

I'm trying to run my desktop chrome extension on Android, so i tried running it in Yandex browser on my phone. It runs ok except for the google login.(everything works well on desktop Chrome and desktop Yandex). 
This code is called by the background scripts:

```
var url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth' +
    '?client_id=' + clientId +
    '&response_type=id_token' +
    '&access_type=offline' +
    '&redirect_uri=' + redirectUri +
    '&scope=' + scopes;

getIdToken: function (message) {
    const _this = this;
    var idToken = "";
    chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
        {
            'url': url,
            'interactive': true
        },

    function (redirectedTo) {
        console.log("[2]auth-manager called: "+redirectedTo);
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            // Example: Authorization page could not be loaded.
            console.log("lastError: "+chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        }
        else {
            var response = redirectedTo.split('#', 2)[1];
            // Example: id_token=<YOUR_BELOVED_ID_TOKEN>&authuser=0&hd=<SOME.DOMAIN.PL>&session_state=<SESSION_SATE>&prompt=<PROMPT>
            idToken = (response.split('&')[0]).split('=', 2)[1];
            console.log("auth-manager id token", idToken);
            if (message != undefined) {
                message.data.google_id_token = idToken;
                cloudWebSocket.sendMessage(JSON.stringify(message));
                _this.isLogged = true;
                closePopup();
                alert('login successful');
            }
        }
    }
);
```

}

When I call this function, redirectedTo is undefined, and i get a chrome.runtime.lastError.message:"canceled". That's it.

I use the very same manifest from the desktop apps, with the same clientId,redirectUri and scopes.
I can't figure out, what causes this problem?
If there's another way to perform a google login without this issue it can also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the [Web Extensions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/identity/launchWebAuthFlow) ...in particular the platform support table there.

initiating the oAuth2 flow on the server-side should nevertheless be possible.

Comment: but it's chrome.identity. Or are they basically the same? for now i found https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-identity perhaps it would work?

Comment: @orish that `Cordova` plugin only fakes `chrome.identity`; it uses Play Services to login, instead - within the sand-boxed scope of a Chrome extension, you won't have any access to that `WebView` nor to `Cordova` plugins. these are two whole different scopes, despite both are `Webkit` based.